# Grounding with a wood table vs a metal table standing on a carpet floor

Tags: laptop, ground, esd

I have the acer nitro 5 AN515-53.

I'm standing on carpet flooring and I suspect that will produce static electricity overtime.
Would a wood table and metal table have the same grounding properties as long as they are on the floor I'm standing on? How do they differ as conductive vs non-conductive material?

Do I need to feel the "shock" from touching something conductive to be grounded? Would I feel that shock from touching wood, and if not would I still be "grounded?"

Answer (score 1):

Neither would be grounded, as neither connect to ground. They're both just a floating potential, the same as you.

If you get static shocks when you touch the water taps or large electrical appliances - fridge, cooker etc, then I'd start to worry about it… otherwise I wouldn't bother.

Your computer's case is a faraday cage anyway. Even if you get a spike from it, it's being routed to the mains socket's potential [even if the socket's not grounded you still will reach an equilibrium through it.]
Otherwise, only worry about correct grounding if you're working inside it.

Answer (score 1):

***In general, this is not something you need to consider...*** if the shocks are distressing for you, or you're asking out of curiosity, please read on.

---

There are two major questions here.

- Are you a "*normal user*" who is just working with their computer, or are you working with bare electronics, exposed PCBs / ICs, etc...?
- Are you getting static shocks, and is this concerning / distressing for you?

For the first question, if you are a "*normal user*", then you shouldn't typically need to worry about it. If you open the computer to perform an upgrade (e.g: more RAM), then carefully ground yourself or match your potential to the computer's chassis by touching / holding the metalwork. But if you're just using the fully assembled equipment, then they are (or should be) designed in such a way to handle this properly.

For the second question, the shocks aren't typically problematic, but they can be very annoying and surprising. Higher energy shocks will present as an arc, possibly with a snapping / cracking sound. If you have a pacemaker or similar, then it might be sensible or more important to look into resolving this.

---

"*Ground*" is generally used as a good solid reference because it's so readily available, but it's not really the major factor - "*potential difference*" is (i.e: the difference in potential / voltage between two objects).

If you're in polyester socks, and polyester trousers, and shuffling around on your polyester carpet, etc... then you can work up quite a large static charge quite quickly. Touching something that is at a different potential can cause a shock regardless of whether one or other is technically "*grounded*". The arc or physical contact causes the potential difference between two objects to reduce.

As above, clothing and other materials can have a large impact on this effect - conductivity being the major consideration. However, other factors such as the humidity in your room can also have a large impact - low humidity (< 40%) reduces the conductivity of the air, and permits a larger buildup of static charge between two objects - conversely higher humididty will decrease the conductivity of the air, and that permits the charge to dissipate more quickly.

---

> Do I need to feel the "shock" from touching something conductive to be grounded?

No. ESD mats are designed specifically to have a fairly high but well defined resistance. Touching one that is correctly setup for a period of a few seconds will disappate your built-up charge, but you won't feel a shock or get an arc (though you may feel it as the charge disappates - e.g: in your hairs).

The shock or arc is the problem for electronics - it is related to a rapid change in potential / transfer of energy, and can cause damage to electronics. A slower discharge brings things to the same potential, but without the damaging effects of a quick discharge.

> Would I feel that shock from touching wood, and if not would I still be "grounded?"

A metal table that is directly connected to earth (e.g: via a socket) will have a low impedance path to ground. You are more likely to feel the discharge, and you are more likely to damage equipment.

A wooden table has a far higher resistance, and therefore you are quite unlikely to feel the discharge, *even though it can / will still happen*.

---

A final couple of points:

- ***Please do not*** play with mains sockets if you don't know what you're doing or have *any* doubts.
- ***Please do not*** connect a metal table directly to ground. A low impedance path will give shocks and can be just as damaging to equipment as a poor / non-ESD-safe environment.

---

Further response to your situation (upgrading components in your computer)... apologies if this is getting long and in-depth.

If it helps, try to think less about being "*grounded*" and more about the "*potential difference*" between objects. Everything is relative, so you can consider your workbench to be your reference point ("*ground-ish*"), and everything around it to be at some potential from that point. Placing equipment on the desk will allow the potential difference (i.e: static charge) between the desk and equipment to equalize over time - even if the desk isn't very conductive (e.g: wood).

Additionally, keep in mind that "*static electricity*" behaves differently to "*current electricity*" ([ref](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/what-is-electricity/static-or-current-electricity)). Static electricity is typically many thousands of volts and up.

Given that wood is (generally speaking) more conductive than air, a build up of static charge on your person will "*dissipate into*" the wooden desk more quickly than it will "*dissipate into*" the surrounding air - but it will likely be significantly slower than using a proper ESD-safe working environment.

I've quoted "*dissipate into*" above, because as I've said, what we really care about here is reducing or removing the potential difference between objects... "*dissipate into*" might not be the best way of thinking about this, but it seems to be common terminology for this effect. "*Equalizing the potential difference*" is really what we're interested in, and probably helps with mentally reasoning about this.

The rate of discharge (or rather, speed at which equilibrium is achieved) is an important factor when working with sensitive electronics. Discharging too fast is bad and potentially damaging (e.g: metal desk tied to ground), while discharging too slowly (e.g: wooden desk) can mean that the charge doesn't have an opportunity to fully dissipate before you let go and start work.

ESD mats and earthing points are designed with a non-zero resistance (typically about 1 MΩ for an earth bonding point). This is so ensure a controlled discharge over a period of time. They are all about *dissipating* the static charge (over time), **not** *discharging* it (quickly).

As above, the "*potential difference*" is by far the most important part. When working with electronics, it is the potential difference between your body (and thus fingers) and the sensitive components (i.e: ICs) which is the concern. Electronic devices with metal chassis (e.g: a PC) are often design with their "*ground*" / 0v / reference tied to the mains-ground and also connected to the chassis. By holding the metal chassis of the equipment, you will bring your body to the same potential, meaning that you are then able to safely handle the components inside. If you aren't wearing an ESD wristband, and you walk up and poke at a PCB directly (instead of touching the enclosure first), then that discharge can occur through the circuit board and/or chips... this may well cause damage.

With this conceptual view, your body can be considered a *tiny* capacitor (~100 pF) charged up to ~15 kV. You can model other objects the same way. With a low impedance path, the discharge can be fast (< 1 μs), which can result in a spark. There is little total energy here, but the voltage (aka: potential difference) is very significant and that small amount of energy transferred can still be damaging. If the path of that fast discharge is *through* sensitive electronics components (i.e: the ICs directly), then damage can definately occur.

So, in summary... if you're not working in an ESD-safe environment:

- Always touch the chassis / enclosure / metalwork before putting your hands into the equipment

  - Every time you walk off and return
  - After taking a top off (*especially* a fleece or similar)
  - Periodically, as a matter of course
- Pick up components by the edge of the PCB wherever possible

  - Don't grab for the board, placing your fingers on the ICs
- Maintaining a low potential difference between yourself and the equipment is more important
- The grounding of your workbench is less important

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I'm just a normal user who is trying to upgrade my RAM/remove my heatsink and redo the thermal paste so I guess I should be fine with my wood table and carpet floor as long as I occasionally ground.

Comment: Correct! Periodically grab hold of the case metalwork (especially if you walk off or when you return), and you should be fine.

Comment: One more thing just to confirm, because wood is already insulative, would it matter if it was grounded? Does it sitting on a carpet floor mean it is at least partially grounded? Can whatever static I built up on my body become discharged through the wood safely, or would no static discharge on the wood? If it did discharge on the wood, would it then cause damage to components which are conductive because it has less resistance or is discharging on wood safe?

Comment: I've added more to my answer... it's getting a bit long now, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm standing on carpet flooring and I suspect that will produce static
> electricity overtime. Would a wood table and metal table have the same
> grounding properties as long as they are on the floor I'm standing on?

(1) Wood is not conductive. Carpet is not conductive in general (some carpets have metal threads woven in to reduce static.

Working on a Wood Table standing on carpet will not protect your gear and static could damage it.

(2) Metal table is fine.  Make sure the metal table is grounded to your room ground (electrical ground). Attach a wire to the table and to the ground screw of an electrical outlet.

You can get a metal bracelet that you can attach to the table so when you work on your gear you and it will be safe.

You can also get a mat to stand on the will help control electrostatic discharge.

From your post, I assume you have the option of a wooden table (not at all conductive) and a metal table (will be conductive).

Comment: Thank you, is the metal table not grounded by standing on my carpet? The entire floor is made of carpet so I'm not sure how to attach it.

Comment: Attach the table by wire to the ground screw of an electrical outlet.

Comment: Attaching the table to an outlet is still useless, the wooden surface won't conduct. You need an ESD mat and a tag to an earth pin for good ground.

Comment: I meant the metal table. Agree with you about the wooden table.

Comment: This misses some basic physics application. The desk is a red herring. Grounding it is not a fix.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering why would a metal table be dangerous? If I wanted to ground myself with the table if it was not grounded vs grounded, is it because the electricity would travel to any parts sitting on the table, and if it was grounded then it would not?

Comment: Also sorry I'm not very aware of attaching wires to outlets, what does a ground screw look like and what do you need to attach it?

Comment: A wall outlet has a screw in the middle that is most likely grounded. Attach there or remove the cover and attach to a ground screw. Be most careful.

Comment: Wall outlets, or as we know them over here 'sockets' vary by territory. Some are compulsorily earthed, many are not. It is highly **not** recommended to play with sockets unless you are qualified. This answer & comments are building towards a potentially dangerous hand waving of 'science'.

Comment: "Conductivity" isn't a binary "is" vs "is not"... low impedance paths (e.g: metal table tied to ground) can be just as damaging and shocking as non-ESD-safe environments.

Comment: Hmm . Proper Grounding has served me well with delicate instruments over a period of years. Never any static or damage.

Comment: Grounding of the equipment itself works because the case is a faraday cage - any imbalance in potential will run round the case to earth, not through the components. It's a sound policy [assuming you live somewhere where earthed sockets are compulsory] though bypassed [badly imo] by modern switch-mode PSUs that don't even run an earth to the PSU itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the type of table completely, and invest in an ESD mat, wrist-band and earth socket to ensure a proper ground. Otherwise, all bets are off.

[image]

Comment: This is required only if disassembling computers. I think the OP is already too worried about a non-issue.